# Why does Stockfish only gives -28 to a game with only a W pawn and a B rook remaining, while it should be resolved in perfect play?

Tags: checkmate, stockfish, draw, evaluation, blunder

In this position (W resigned) with only a pawn and a rook remaining Stockfish should have resolved the game and say "Mate in xx" (with perfect play).

However Stockfish is said to have resolved any game having less than 7 pieces, but it "only" evaluates to -28.

[image]

Stockfish is smart but I doubt it knowing that I'm still able to blunder my R at this time :)

I don't see any way for W to draw here, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are running it at a shallow depth. My old version of Stockfish recognizes that there is a mate when it gets to depth 32.

There are tablebases available, which engines like Stockfish can use, that have chess solved for 7 or fewer pieces. The instance of Stockfish you're using probably just doesn't use them. (The 7 man tablebase is something like 18.4 terabytes in size; if you're running this locally I'm guessing you don't have the space for it.)